# how %c prints value in a C program?

Tags: c

The following program yields 12480 as the output.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char c=48;
    int i, mask=01;
    for(i=1; i<=5; i++)
    {
        printf("%c", c|mask);
        mask = mask<<1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now, my question is, how "%c" prints the integer value 1, 2, 4, 8, 0 after every loop. It should print a character as a value. If i simply use the following program,

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char c=48;
    int i, mask=01;
    printf("%c",c); 
    return 0;
}
```

it prints 0 but when i change the identifier %c to %d it prints 48 . Can anyone please tell me how is this going!?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use `%c`, c prints the corresponding ASCII key for the integer value.

Binary of 48 is 110000.
Binary of 1 is 000001.

You `or` them, `110000 | 000001` gives `110001` which is equivalent to `49 in decimal base 10`.

According to the [ASCII table](http://web.cs.mun.ca/~michael/c/ascii-table.html), corresponding ascii values for 49, 50, 51, etc are '1', '2', '3', etc.

Comment: just one thing the binary of 48 is 110000 not 110001

Comment: @user975234 Oops, I had the final result in mind, so mistyped it.

Answer (score 3):

It actually prints out the *characters* `'1'`, `'2'`, `'4'` etc.

The numeric value of `c|mask` gets interpreted as an [ASCII code](http://www.asciitable.com/). The ASCII code of `'0'` is 48.

To make the code a little clearer, you could change

```
char c=48;
```

to

```
char c='0';
```

The two forms are equivalent.

Comment: thanks for your answer @aix .. but tell me how is the OR operation is being performed? I mean is the OR operation being done using 48's binary or 0's binary?

Comment: @user975234: `48` gets ORed with `1`, giving `49`. When you print out `49` using `%c`, you get `1` on the screen, since `49` is the ASCII code of the character `'1'`.